# Accord.net NaiveBayesLearning "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, .net-core, accord.net

I am using Accord.net 3.7.0 in dot net core 1.1.

The algorithm I use is naive bayesian. And the source code of the learning mechanism is as follows:

```
    public LearningResultViewModel NaiveBayes(int[][] inputs, int[] outputs)
    {
        // Create a new Naive Bayes learning
        var learner = new NaiveBayesLearning();

        // Learn a Naive Bayes model from the examples
        NaiveBayes nb = learner.Learn(inputs, outputs);

        #region test phase
        // Compute the machine outputs
        int[] predicted = nb.Decide(inputs);

        // Use confusion matrix to compute some statistics.
        ConfusionMatrix confusionMatrix = new ConfusionMatrix(predicted, outputs, 1, 0);
        #endregion

        LearningResultViewModel result = new LearningResultViewModel()
        {
            Distributions = nb.Distributions,
            NumberOfClasses = nb.NumberOfClasses,
            NumberOfInputs = nb.NumberOfInputs,
            NumberOfOutputs = nb.NumberOfOutputs,
            NumberOfSymbols = nb.NumberOfSymbols,
            Priors = nb.Priors,
            confusionMatrix = confusionMatrix
        };

        return result;
    }
```

I have tested this piece of code on a little data but as data grew the

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

error occurred.

As I can't navigate in the `Learn` method so I don't know what to do. the screen shot of the run-time is this:

[image: Run-time error screen shot]

No extra information, no inner exception no IDEA!!!

TG.

// UPDATE_1 ***

The inputs array is a 180 by 4 matrix (array) as the bellow image shows:

[image: Inputs]

which has 4 columns in every row. checked by hand (I can share its video too if needed!!!)

The outputs array is a 180 one as shown here:

[image: Outputs]

which only contains 0 and 1 (I can share its video too if needed!!!).

And about NaiveBayesinLearning doc is here:

[NaiveBayesinLearning](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_Bayes_NaiveBayesLearning.htm)

More examples bottom of this page:

[More examples](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_Bayes_NaiveBayes.htm)

And the `learn` method docs here:

[learn method doc](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_MachineLearning_Bayes_NaiveBayesLearningBase_4_Learn_1.htm)

Comment: I think we might be guessing as much as you, possibly more so.. Is your `inputs` array rectangular? What documentation do you have about `Learn`? Is it expecting that the outputs array is the same length as a particular input array etc.. You might have to decompile whatever library codes for that `Learn` method so you can see how it accesses the arrays

Comment: We cannot see the code that throws the exception, we don't know what you pass to that method, but we can guess why it fails?

Comment: @CaiusJard May be some one encountered this before. But it is also ok that I test your guesses. Yes in this example inputs is a 180 by 4 array and the output is a 180 vector.

Comment: @oerkelens I will append the more info to the question as you noted. just a minute.

Comment: Is the inputs surely fully populated with 180 instances of a 4-long array?

Comment: @All I have added some extra information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the comments and the Ideas from them I have suspected to the values of matrix. So I have investigated it:

[image: problem]

As shown in image above, some rows have below zero values. The inputs matrix is generated by Codification which is used in the examples of here:

[NaiveBayes](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_Bayes_NaiveBayes.htm)

with the docs below:

[Codification docs](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Filters_Codification.htm)

the codification -1 was with the values of null. Like the screen shot below:

[image: one of problematic records]

So my solution was replacing `null` values with `"null"`. But may be there is better solutions.

Now the caller method that contains fixed data is as follows:

```
    public LearningResultViewModel Learn(EMVDBContext dBContext, string userId, LearningAlgorithm learningAlgorithm)
    {
        var learningDataRaw = dBContext.Mutants
            .Include(mu => mu.MutationOperator)
            .Where(mu => mu.Equivalecy == 0 || mu.Equivalecy == 10);

        string[] featureTitles = new string[] {
        "ChangeType",
        "OperatorName",
        "OperatorBefore",
        "OperatorAfter",
        };

        string[][] learningInputNotCodified = learningDataRaw.Select(ldr => new string[] {
            ldr.ChangeType.ToString(),
            ldr.MutationOperator.Name??"null",
            ldr.MutationOperator.Before??"null",
            ldr.MutationOperator.After??"null",
        }).ToArray();

        int[] learningOutputNotCodified = learningDataRaw.Select(ldr => ldr.Equivalecy == 0 ? 0 : 1).ToArray();

        #region Codification phase
        // Create a new codification codebook to
        // convert strings into discrete symbols
        Codification codebook = new Codification(featureTitles, learningInputNotCodified);

        // Extract input and output pairs to train
        int[][] learningInput = codebook.Transform(learningInputNotCodified);

        switch (learningAlgorithm)
        {
            case LearningAlgorithm.NaiveBayesian:
                return learningService.NaiveBayes(learningInput, learningOutputNotCodified);
                break;
            case LearningAlgorithm.SVM:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        #endregion

        return null;
    }
```

I wish this will help the others encountering same problem.

Comment: The proper solution depends on how you would like to deal with null values. The codification filter can be configured to map null values to some predetermined value through its "DefaultMissingValueReplacement" property. However, there are other possible strategies too, such as removing variables (columns) or instances (rows) where null values can occur. That's the only reason why the framework doesn't handle them automatically, but surely the exception should have had a better message!

Comment: @Cesar as the learning algorithms have problem with negative values, I think it is better for codification to be configured not to use -1 as default or as you mentioned have better exception message.

Comment: @Cesar I have tested this piece of code `Codification codebook = new Codification(featureTitles, learningInputNotCodified)
            {
                DefaultMissingValueReplacement = 0
            };` but still it generates -1 in the place of null values. Would you please write right code. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, the column-specific options are being created before the default missing value is set... As a workaround, you can set them directly using ```codebook["OperatorName"].MissingValueReplacement = 0``` after the codebook has been constructed. This should force them to be replaced by the value you want.

Comment: Thanks @Cesar, this is also a good solution. Accord.net is awesome.